# Android Studio Giraffe - WEAR OS - Only compose?

Tags: android-studio, wear-os, android-studio-girafee

I got the Android Studio Giraffe installed on a new computer... While trying to create a new project it doesnt show me the options for creating a view project like the previous version (or choose the language), only "compose for wear os"...

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?? For other kinds of devices it shows...

Thanks!

Comment: The temporary "solution" I found was to create a "No activity" project and then add the activities... not the best way, but the only way I found hahaha I'm still looking for a solution, if there is one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new project with wear os then select No activity and after that create an Empty Views Activity [image] with the image and add the below code to the manifest file.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Nav" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.wear.mobileapp.NewActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />
</application>
```

Comment: Yeah, I did this process... but there used to be a template...

Comment: For New Version We don't have option like previous version.

Comment: Which is weird... I know google is "killing" java, so it makes sense they remove views... but there isnt even the "watch face" option showing... I still think I'm missing something