In Android Studio Ladybug, how do you start a New Project for Wear OS with an Empty Wear App that generates a MainActvity.java?
I can get Ladybug to create only a MainActivity.kt and not a MainActivity.java. The app is for Wear OS, not for Phone and Tablet.  How do you create a java app for a wearable in Android Studio Ladybug?

Why would you want a MainActvity.java? A bit hacky, but you can always try to convert the Kotlin file (that's what kt stands for) to a Java file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file

Create a "No activity" project and then add the activities... for more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407183/11632959

For either of the two suggestions in the above comments, could someone give an example of say, the Hello World app, created in Kotlin (. kt) (or created as a No activity app) and changed to Java (.java) using Ladybug.
